# Two objects interating with a third without knowing about each other

Tags: c#, oop

Suppose I have two classes, `Foo` and `Bar`, shown bellow:

```cs
public class Foo{

private Bar _bar;

public int Value { get; private set; }

public void UpdateValue(Bar bar) 
{
    // Update Value, say:
    Value++;
    // What do I put here to change bar?
}

// Bunch of methods.

}

public class Bar{

private List<Foo> _foos;

public bool Value {get; private set; }

public void UpdateValue(Foo foo)
{
    // Update Value, say:
    Value = !Value;
    
    // What do I put here to change foo?

}

// A bunch of other methods.

}
```

I want to have two instances of `Foo`, say `fooA` and `fooB`, and one instance of `bar`. `bar` contains copy references to both `Foo` instances, and each `Foo` instance contains a copy reference to `bar`. The idea being that `bar` "knows" `fooA` and `fooB`, and vice-versa, but `fooA` doesn't know about `fooB`.

I wan't to have both `fooA` and `fooB` interacting with `bar`, without interacting with one another. Say, if `fooA` changes something about `bar`, `fooB` must be told about these changes, without necessarily knowing if `bar` changed itself, or if something else changed `bar`. I want both `fooA` and `fooB` and `bar` to have the most up-to-date information about one-another at all times. The thing is, I'm not sure the best way to implement these interactions.

Is there a good way, according to best-practices, to do this? Or better yet, how do I make both `foo` instances interact with `bar` to change each other inside values simuntaneously without getting to know each other (any change is valid, I'm only trully worried about how the interaction can be implemented).

Comment: Do you want `Foo` and `Bar` to implement `INotifyChanges`? And register to each other's events?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `INotifyChanges`. But if it helps fix the problem, then I don't mind! Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
public class Foo
{
    private Bar _bar;

    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public void UpdateValue(Bar bar)
    {
        // Update Value, say:
        Value++;
        // What do I put here to change bar?
        bar.UpdateValue(this);
    }

    // Bunch of methods.

}

public class Bar
{

    private List<Foo> _foos;

    public bool Value { get; private set; }

    public void UpdateValue(Foo foo)
    {
        // Update Value, say:
        Value = !Value;

        // What do I put here to change foo?
        foo.UpdateValue(this);
    }

    // A bunch of other methods.

}
```

But then you end up with some endless recursion.

So you need to specify a terminal condition where one update will *not* call the other update.

For example

```
    public void UpdateValue(Foo foo)
    {
        // Update Value, say:
        Value = !Value;
        if(Value) 
        {
            // What do I put here to change foo?
            foo.UpdateValue(this);
        }
    }
```

This will ensure an end to one method calling the other.

There just isn't enough information in the question to understand your *intent* with just this code snippet.

Also, note that both `Foo` and `Bar` are classes which means references such as `_bar` will always point to the most up-to-date information. They don't store a copy of `Bar` but point to the memory where the `Bar` object is defined. So there is no need to push changes around unless the state of one class depends on the state of the other.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry if my information was vague. I'm trying to solve a complex problem without sharing its details. 

Your input was indeed valuable. I can have `Foo` and `Bar` call each other internally and have some sort of termination condition to avoid endless recursion!

Also, `bar` can call a function for each one of its internal `foo` references! Thank you!